# boxplot() still displays boxes for categories I've dropped by deleting corresponding rows

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I have derived a new data frame `major.groups` from an existing data frame `antiques` by removing data from 2 categories:

```
major.groups <- antiques[antiques$Group!="Boxes" & antiques$Group!="Metalware",]
```

However, when I use `boxplot()`, `Boxes` and `Metalware` still appear on the x-axis (obviously with no corresponding data).

How can I exclude these when working with the new data frame `major.groups`? I can obviously remove them outside of R and re-import - but I'm sure there must be a better way.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without reproducible example, I am unable to test this. But this should work:

```
major.groups <- droplevels(antiques[antiques$Group!="Boxes" & antiques$Group!="Metalware",])
```

Note that `boxplot()` displays values for all existing factor levels:

```
 If multiple groups are supplied either as multiple arguments or
 via a formula, parallel boxplots will be plotted, in the order of
 the arguments or the order of the levels of the factor (see
 ‘factor’).
```

For a factor, dropping values does not mean dropping levels. Try this:

```
x <- factor(letters[1:4])
#[1] a b c d
#Levels: a b c d
x[-1]
#[1] b c d
#Levels: a b c d
droplevels(x[-1])
#[1] b c d
#Levels: b c d
```